# [Vue warn]: Property or method "Boston" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm setting up some props, as shown below.

Component 1 (Parent):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{agency1}}</span>
    <span>{{workstation}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  name: "work-station-view",
  props: {
    agency1: {
      type: String
    },
    workstation: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Component 2 (Child):

```html
<template>
  <WorkStationView :workstation="1.1" :agency1="Boston" />
</template>
```

The `workstation` prop renders fine, but the `agency1` prop doesn't show up at all. I get this message from Vue in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "Boston" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I checked the docs, as it says to define it in `data()`, so I did a combination of all of these (probably more) to no avail:

```js
// attempt 1
data() {
  agency1 = this.agency1;
  return {};
}

// attempt 2
data() {        
  return {
    agency1 = this.agency1;
  };
}

// attempt 3
data() {       
  return {
    agency1: '';
  };
}
```

If I use a number value for `agency1` (`<WorkStationView :workstation="1.1" :agency1="3" />`), it shows! What is going on?

Comment: Also your templates look wrong, `<template>` must have only one child element, but you have 2 spans in it.

Comment: @AlexanderKim Yeah, they are wrapped in a div. Actually, there is a lot more than this span tags. I removed all of that for simplicity purposes in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:agency1="Boston"` is [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) for `v-bind:agency1="Boston"`. It attempts to bind a data property named `Boston`, but you don't have one defined. `:agency1="3"` works because `3` is a literal. If you were attempting to assign the literal string "Boston" to `agency1`, don't use the preceding colon:

```html
<!--
<WorkStationView :agency1="Boston">
--> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->

<WorkStationView agency1="Boston">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using an inline string, you should skip the `:` or quote your string.

The `:` is short-hand for `v-bind` and is expected to be used with variables that you're binding when passing attributes from the parent component to the child. In this case, you don't have a variable called `Boston` in the parent context, and hence the error from Vue.

If all you want to do is use a constant string like `Boston`, just use it like
 `<WorkstationView :workstation="1.1" :agency="'Boston'" />`

Alternatively, it would've also worked if you did the following:

`<WorkstationView :workstation="1.1" agency="Boston" />`